# It is safe to use i+1 in O(n) searching?

Tags: c++, c

I'm asking myself if it is safe to use `i+1` to check if the next number is the same as current... Example :

```
int search(int el, int* a, int n) {

if(a == NULL && n<0)
{
    return NULL;
}

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    if((a[i] == el )&& (a[i+1] != el)) // here I check next element
    {
        return i; // if I find it, return a position.
    }
}

return -1; // else return -1
}
```

If we have an array with length `4`, then `a[i+1]` will be passed an array length, but program will still work.

Comment: I think you can better ask this on [codereview.se]

Comment: And why are you comparing with the next one? If n is the array size, it accesses the n+1 element, undefined behaviour.

Comment: When `i` is 3 you try to access `a[4]`, which isn't there. It's not working!

Comment: At the very least it will not be safe. a[i+1] will point outside the array, unless you loop till (n-1), and this can cause a segmentation fault or, at the very least, a comparison with an unknown quantity (which could lead to the comparison occasionally being true, and a bug that's difficult to track). You ought to decide what to do when inspecting the last element, and do that, instead of relying on a undefined behavior.

Comment: @WouterJ The OP's asking a very specific question - he's not asking for a review of his code.

Comment: You can access the i+1th entry without violating O(n), but you must somehow assure that i+1 is less than the bounds of the array.

Comment: Not related to your question, but I believe your initial test should use logical or (||). Not the logical and (&&). So if(a == NULL || n<0).

Answer (score 1):

No, accessing elements out of bounds is **Undefined Behavior**.

Your program may "seem" to work, but you cannot expect anything out of it. It could work on your machine, and crash on another one. Or it could work on all machines *now*, but not tomorrow. You should check if the index is out-of-bounds before using the subscript operator.

You may consider changing your cycle so that it never accesses out-of-bounds elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
//                  ^^^^^
```

Then, you would have to take care of the last element in the array separately, as a special case.

Comment: "You may consider changing your cycle so that it never accesses out-of-bounds elements" but changing the limit of the `for` it wouldn't recognize a sequence that ends at the end of the array.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: If I understood correctly what the OP is trying to do, the function should check whether two consecutive elements have the same input value. But if the (n-1)-th and the (n-th) elements don't have it, then there is no point in repeating the check for the n-th and (n+1)-th. Or did I get it wrong?

Comment: Hm, I understood that he's looking for a sequence of elements with value `el`, and wants to return the index of the last element of such a sequence (hence why he checks if the current element corresponds to `el` but the next doesn't); the last element is a special case, since it ends the sequence anyway.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Oh, right, I see what you mean. I don't have time to rework the algorithm now (my answer was mostly focused on pointing out why it "seems" to work even though the program is illegal), but I added a note. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct, when `i` reaches its last value (`n-1`) you check the value of a nonexistent element (the C standard allows you to have a pointer to one-after-last element, but not to dereference it).

You can fix your code like this:

```
 if((a[i] == el ) && ((i == n-1) || (a[i+1] != el)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `n` is the last element in the array, then `i + 1` is safe in this case. If `n` is the number of elements in the array, `i + 1` may appear to work most of the time, but it is *not* safe.

In that case, you're accessing an element outside the bounds of the array, which may do anything from giving you incorrect results to crashing your program. Most of the time it will appear to work, though, making the problem very hard to debug when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me what you're asking. Even if array access is expensive, accessing both `a[i]` and `a[i+1]` remains of O(N) complexity. What you *can't* do is adding complexity that's based on `i` (for example an additional loop from 0 to `i`), or modifying `i` (for example decrementing it based on some condition).

The problem, as others have already pointed out, is that the last element is compared to a nonexistent datum: either you'll get an error and a possible crash, or the program will *appear* to be working - and actually work *most* of the time - until the time where that unknown and possibly random last-and-one item will trigger the comparison, and yield an unexpected result.

You should check that the array size is at least 1 (that ought to be a special case anyway, can't run a compare on a single element!) and then loop only up to `n-1`. Or you could save the previous value in a temporary variable; depending on the platform, this will be a (possibly much faster) register, or a (possibly much slower) stack location. In most cases I'd just state my intention of comparing with the next element, as you did, and let the compiler sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

No.

```
int main(void)
{
    char pumpkin[8];
    int a[4];
    int i, p;

    a[0] = 3760;
    a[1] = 100001;
    a[2] = 595959;
    a[3] = 1886221680;

    pumpkin[0] = 'p';
    pumpkin[1] = 'u';
    pumpkin[2] = 'm';
    pumpkin[3] = 'p';

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        p = search(a[i], a, 4);

        if (p >= 0)
            printf("Found it at position %d: %d.\n", p, a[i]);
        else
            printf("Value not found.\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
```

In my machine:

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -o boundserror boundserror.c
$ ./boundserror 
Found it at position 0: 3760.
Found it at position 1: 100001.
Found it at position 2: 595959.
Value not found.
```

What happened ? Compiler wrote value 1886221680 both in a[3] and where a[4] would be if it existed. About the program working on your machine: read about the works on my machine concept.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/the-works-on-my-machine-certification-program.html